# Iterate over lists in dataframe cells

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe where some cells contain lists, and I want to iterate through each item in each list with a simple print statement.

```
      Date     Names
0  2018_Q1     ['Faye', 'Mark', 'Shay', 'Alex']
1  2019_Q1     ['Pete', 'Alan', 'Stan', 'Faye']
2  2019_Q2     Mike
```

For example, the output should look something like:

```
2018_Q1
- Faye
- Mark
- Shay
- Alex

2019_Q1
- Pete
- Alan
- Stan
- Faye

2019_Q2
- Mike
```

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
out =  df.Date + ':' + df.Names.str.join(',')
```

Comment: Thanks, although what if I want to iterate over the lists (I updated the desired output to better reflect this)?